# React Native html render: issues with images

Tags: react-native

I try to load HTML from a JSON endpoint, displaying it in the app.
This works good using some libraries, but the HTML content does also contain IMAGES on the bottom.

These images are stacked on top of each other instead of nicely centered next to each other.

How can i make this happen?
And which module is best to use for this?

A snippet below.
Not sure how to style this correctly :(

````
"&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;Title –&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/strong&gt; This a little text.&lt;/p&gt;\n&lt;p&gt;This a little text&lt;/p&gt;\n&lt;div id='gallery-4' class='gallery galleryid-114867 gallery-columns-4 gallery-size-thumbnail'&gt;&lt;figure class='gallery-item'&gt;\n\t\t\t&lt;div class='gallery-icon landscape'&gt;\n\t\t\t\t&lt;a href='https://urltosite/2020/02/28/photo/photo_2020-02-28_19-38-38/&apos;&gt;&lt;img width=\"150\" height=\"150\" src=\"https://urltosite/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/photo_2020-02-28_19-38-38-150x150.jpg?v=1582915513\"; class=\"attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail\" alt=\"\" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;\n\t\t\t&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/figure&gt;&lt;figure class='gallery-item'&gt;\n\t\t\t&lt;div class='gallery-icon landscape'&gt;\n\t\t\t\t&lt;a href='https://urltosite/2020/02/28/phtoto/photo_2020-02-28_19-38-42-2/&apos;&gt;&lt;img width=\"150\" height=\"150\" src=\"https://urltosite/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/photo_2020-02-28_19-38-42-1-150x150.jpg?v=1582915516\"; class=\"attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail\" alt=\"\" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;\n\t\t\t&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/figure&gt;&lt;figure class='gallery-item'&gt;\n\t\t\t&lt;div class='gallery-icon landscape'&gt;\n\t\t\t\t&lt;a href='https://www.urltosite/2020/02/28/phtot/photo_2020-02-28_19-38-46/&apos;&gt;&lt;img width=\"150\" height=\"150\" src=\"https://urltosite/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/photo_2020-02-28_19-38-46-150x150.jpg?v=1582915518\"; class=\"attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail\" alt=\"\" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;\n\t\t\t&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/figure&gt;&lt;figure class='gallery-item'&gt;\n\t\t\t&lt;div class='gallery-icon landscape'&gt;\n\t\t\t\t&lt;a href='https://urltosite/2020/02/28/photo/photo_2020-02-28_19-38-48/&apos;&gt;&lt;img width=\"150\" height=\"150\" src=\"https://urltosite/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/photo_2020-02-28_19-38-48-150x150.jpg?v=1582915521\"; class=\"attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail\" alt=\"\" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;\n\t\t\t&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/figure&gt;\n\t\t&lt;/div&gt;\n\n"```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `react-native-render-html` and specify a style using tagsStyles and classesStyles props for each html tags or classes. The following code is an example of using this props:

```js
<HTML
   html={item.message}
   tagsStyles={{
      p: {
          fontSize: 22,
          lineHeight: 30,
          marginBottom: 0
      },
      img: {
          ...
      }
   }}
   classesStyles={{
      'custom-image': { 
           ... 
      } 
   }}
   ignoredStyles={['line-height']} />
```

also you can use `renderers` props to render custom contents for specific tags. for more information about `react-native-render-html` follow this link:
https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html

Comment: That indeed looks promising, although i cannot get it too work and align the images in the html next to eachother. :(

The rest of the styling i understand but maybe you have hints on manipulationg the alignment of the images?

Comment: for example you have a **div** with class **gallery-columns-4** in html content of your question and want to style to images in it that images stay on a row. for this situation you must use this code:

`<HTML
   html={item.message}
   tagsStyles={{
      img: {
          ...
      }
   }}
   classesStyles={{
      'gallery-columns-4': { 
           flexDirection:"row"
      } ,
      'gallery-item':{
           flex:1
      }
   }} />`

Comment: You can use the **width** with percent value instead of **flex:1** and add **flexWrap:"wrap"** to **gallery-columns-4** class

Comment: Sorry for late response. The last solution works :D

Can i use this module also to scrape ads from a website?
Meaning: there is an advertisers page, with all the advertisers on it. This can be parses by the API, but contains a lot of html ofcourse. It contains css styles, title, decription and image. 

Can i map this and put it in an object somehow with this module?